# How to reapply eventlistener on a computed array of divs in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseevent

I would like to display an array of divs, with the goal of adding a class on the div itself and on a child element when hovering the div.

The array of divs are the result of a computed function. Here's the code:

```html
 <article
    v-for="(article, index) in filteredArticles"
    :key="article.id"
    ref="articleRefs"
    :ref-key="index"
    @mouseenter="handleClass(index, 'add')"
    @mouseleave="handleClass(index, 'remove')"
>
    <!-- Content -->
</article
```

```js
const articleRefs = ref<HTMLDivElement[]>([])
const articleList = ref([] as Article[])

const filteredArticles = computed(() => {
    return activeTag.value !== ''
        ? articleList.value.filter((a) => a.tags.some((t) => t.Tag_id.title === activeTag.value))
        : articleList.value
})

watch(
    filteredArticles.value,
    () => articleRefs.value = []
)

const handleClass = (index: number, action: 'add'|'remove') => {
    const hoveredArticle = articleRefs.value[index]
    hoveredArticle.classList[action]('animate')
    hoveredArticle.querySelector('h2')?.classList[action]('glitch')
}
```

When the page loads, everything works, and as long as I change the tags to display an article that didn't get filtered out, my `handleClass` methods works / gets called.

However, if an article filtered out gets displayed again, nothing happens on hovering.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See if there's a change in behaviour if you make that computed a regular method; might give you a clue. I would keep scrutinizing that aspect, and why the @mouseenter/mouseleave seems to only apply on initial render. In any case, absolute worst-case scenario (which I don't think you should need to do) you could put a single listener on the entire container rather than individual list items, then just analyze the mouse target to see whether it's a legit list item or not, then run your handleClass logic on the target.

Comment: @MarsAndBack it's weird, because according to my browser's inspector, there IS a mouseEvent registered for the articles, no matter what's displayed. The events simply don't get triggered. I'll try your suggestion but honestly, the listener on the entire container doesn't seem too far fetched to me

Comment: Who knows; maybe listeners have context? Or maybe some of your elements are overlapping (ie z-index) after the list changes? Anyways the global listener does have the benefit that it's only one single listener (as opposed to potentially 100's?). To make it easier, maybe use a data attribute in the v-for (e.g. `:data-aListItem='index'`), then you can quickly check if the target has that when the listener triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem, if you use the index of your array that loops through the articles and try to map it to the index of the refs. If you look into the [vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) you will see, that the order of the items is not guaranteed the same as of your data array

> It should be noted that the ref array does not guarantee the same order as the source array.

This will lead to the problem, that when using the index of the for loop, you might have a different index in your refs array.

### Solution

The idea is to separate your data logic from the presentation logic with a new `SingleArticle` Vue Component (the naming might be different depending on your context, but it is suggested to have at least a two word component name.). If you build it as follows, the Vue framework will make sure, your update logic works and you don’t need to care for that.

#### 1. Single Article Component

- the root class `animated` is applied from the framework depending on the hover state
- As I understood from the context, the contents of the article are passed as HTML string, so you need to use `querySelector` to get the element inside the contents and apply a class to it.

```html
<!-- vue sfc template: -->
<article
  ref="articleRef"
  :class="{ animated: isHover }"
  v-html="content"
  @mouseenter="isHover = true"
  @mouseleave="isHover = false"
/>
```

```
// vue sfc script (or script setup)
import { ref, defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'SingleArticle',
  props: {
    // what ever is in your article props
    // but I add some example props to showcase the idea
    content: String,
    // ...
  },
  setup(props) {
    var articleRef = ref<HTMLElement>(null);
    var isHover = ref<boolean>(false);

    watch(isHover, (currIsHover) => {
      const action = currIsHover ? 'add' : 'remove';
      articleRef.value?.querySelector('h2')?.classList[action]('glitch');
    });
    
    return {
      articleRef,
      isHover,
    }
  }
});
```

#### 2. use the new component within `v-for`

```html
<!-- inside the vue sfc template -->
<single-article
 v-for="(article, index) in filteredArticles"
 :key="article.id"
 :content="article.content"
/>
```

```
// the main component only contains the logic for the
// filtering and the hovering logic is completely done
// inside the new single article component.
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const articleList = ref<Article[]>([]);

    const filteredArticles = computed(() => {
      if (!activeTag.value) return articleList.value;

      return articleList.value.filter(
        (a) => a.tags.some((t) => t.Tag_id.title === activeTag.value)
      );
    }
    
    return {
      filteredArticles,
    };
  }
})
```

### final thoughts and remarks

I didn't test the implementation, this is just written down from what was in my mind.

The solution will separate the filter logic from the presentation logic of the article which will give your two clean components, that are easy to test and also easy to understand. The updates will work out of the box, as vue will cater reactively for it.

Comment: I changed a few things but I didn't think once about exporting the articles in their own component and letting them handle the mouse event themselves. Damnit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, happy I could help ;)